# Magento 2 Cloud | Include database backup to deployment on magento cloud (avoid doing database backup manually before deployment)

Tags: magento, magento2

How can I include database backup to deployment process on magento cloud so that I dont have to do it manually before deployment.

I thought about adjusting deploy.xml scenario and add additional step for database dump (https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/develop/deploy/scenario-based.html?lang=en).

How can I achieve that or is there some better solution?

Maybe some adjustments only in .magento.app.yaml file and avoid adjusting scenarios?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a shell script to perform the database dump, add it to your code base, and invoke it as a step in deploy.xml workflow scripts on both build and deploy phases. This gives full control. Also you can move the backup script into the .magento/hooks folder and configure repo.xml to trigger on pre-deploy - avoiding deploy.xml changes.